# jQuery Mobile on PhoneGap/Cordova shrinking all content into small space at top, only on devices

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm attempting to build a PhoneGap/Cordova app on the [IBM Worklight](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/) platform using jQuery Mobile, and am having some very strange behaviour in the output that is being generated.

The preview of my app appears OK in Eclipse and a desktop web browser, however when I deploy to a device it appears that the `header` and `content` divs are squeezed into a very small space at the top of the screen, as shown below

[image]

I'm really at a loss as to why this is happening, I've asked on the [Worklight forums](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=450133&tstart=15) but none of the responses there have helped, I'm wondering if its an issue specific to jQuery Mobile?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new project
2. Copy in the code pasted below for `enter.html`
3. Copy in the code pasted below for `home.html`
4. Tweak locations for css/js files
5. Build and deploy app
6. Observe the same behaviour as shown in the screenshot

I'm running these versions :

- IBM Worklight 5.0.1-299-developer-edition
- jQuery 1.7.2 min
- jQuery Mobile 1.1.1
- Eclipse 3.7.2
- Devices : iPhone 4S, Samsung Galaxy S2 & Galaxy Ace, both running 2.3.3

Could there be a conflict between the body element and the jQuery div element both attempting to use the id of "content"?

**enter.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>     
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
        <title>Enter</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body onload="WL.Client.init({})" id="content" style="display: none">

        <div data-role="page" id="enterPage">

            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>AppHeaderHere</h1>
            </div><!-- /header -->

            <div data-role="content">
                <h4 id="eventId">body here</h4>
                <p>

                <a href="home.html" data-role="button">Enter</a>

                Some filler text here, this would be the actual body content
                </p>
            </div><!-- /content -->

            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <h4>Footer here</h4>
            </div>

        </div><!-- /page -->

        <script src="js/MyApp.js"></script>
        <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
        <script src="js/auth.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Home</title> 
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />    
    </head> 
    <body onload="WL.Client.init({})"  id="content" style="display: none"> 

        <div data-role="page" id="homePage">

            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Home</h1>
            </div><!-- /header -->

            <div data-role="content">
                <h4 id="eventId">Some header</h4>
                <p>
                Body content goes here
                </p>
            </div><!-- /content -->

            <div data-role="footer" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="home.html" class="ui-btn-active">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="page1.html">page1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="page2.html">page2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="page3.html">page3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="page4.html">page4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div><!-- /page -->

        <script src="js/MyApp.js"></script>
        <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
        <script src="js/auth.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preview you are using is changing on the fly the CSS of your HTML body. There is a bug there.

If you will Firebug or any similar tool you will see it gives the body a height auto, that overrules the jQuery Mobile CSS. Just comment out the inline CSS and it will work.